# How could we plot the KL divergence?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, machine-learning

I was trying to write a blogpost on information theory and I think it would be a good idea (if possible) to plot the KL divergence in a 3D-plot in order to show graphically its convexity, but I wouldn't know how to define the pdf space. How would you do it?

$$
KL(f||g)=\sum_{x \in X} f(x)\log \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}
$$

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be to use the fact that [a function is convex if and only if its restriction to a line is convex](https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsocoee364a/03ConvexFunctions.pdf).
In the case of KL divergence, we can pick any two pairs of distributions $(f, g)$ and $(f', g')$ and plot
$$
\mathrm{KL}(\lambda f + (1 - \lambda) f' \, || \, \lambda g + (1 - \lambda) g')
$$
as a function of $\lambda$, with $\lambda \in [0, 1]$.

Comment: That's nice, so (formally speaking) in this case we would have that KL is convex if and only if for all the pairs of distributions $(f,g)\in \mathbf{dom}\ \mathrm{KL}$ and all pairs $(f',g')\in \mathbf{dom}\ \mathrm{KL}$, the function $h(\lambda) = \mathrm{KL}(\lambda f + (1 - \lambda) f' \, || \, \lambda g + (1 - \lambda) g')$ (i.e. the function wich define all $\mathrm{KL}$ divergences on the line connecting $(f,g)$ to $(f',g')$) is convex on its domain. Is it right?

Comment: And to show it graphically would it be ok to pick up any pair of distributions such as $(f,g)=(\mathcal{N}(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2),\mathcal{N}(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2))$ and $(f',g')=(\mathcal{N}(\mu_3,\sigma_3^2),\mathcal{N}(\mu_4,\sigma_4^2))$ ?

Comment: That's right! In your particular example (where you choose Gaussian distributions) you will end up computing the KL divergence between mixtures of Gaussians, which can be approximated numerically. Good luck with the finishing touches of your blog-post! :-)